# Want to reverse subarray from the indices given in another 2d array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7, python-3.8

I have an array say `A1=[5,3,2,1,3]` , and another 2D array say `A2 = [[0,1],[1,3]]`. What I want is to reverse the subarrays of `A1` by indices mentioned in each array in `A2`

Like here,

In first operation of A2 i.e. `[0,1]`, it reverses A1 from `A1[0] to A1[1]`
so `A1 becomes = [3,5,2,1,3].`

In second operation of A2 i.e. `[1,3]`, it reverses A1 from `A1[1] to A1[3]`
so `A1 becomes = [3,1,2,5,3].`

So `ANS is [3,1,2,5,3]`

Can anyone tell me how to do it this problem since I am beginner to coding.? I am working in python.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



#function
def reversubarray(arr,start,end):

def performOperations(arr, operations):
   answerarray = arr
   x = oprations.size();
   for i in range(x):
      answerarray = reverseSubarray(arr,operations[x][0],operations[x][1])
   return answerarray;
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    arr_count = int(input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in range(arr_count):
        arr_item = int(input().strip())
        arr.append(arr_item)

    operations_rows = int(input().strip())
    operations_columns = int(input().strip())

    operations = []

    for _ in range(operations_rows):
        operations.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = performOperations(arr, operations)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

I had figured out the brute force approach but how can I write the `reverseSubArray`function here.?

Can anyone share the approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use list slices to easily reverse your sublist -

```
def reversubarray(arr,start,end):
    arr[start:end+1] = arr[start:end+1][::-1]

a = [5,3,2,1,3]

reversubarray(a, 0, 1)
print(a)
```

outputs -

```
[3, 5, 2, 1, 3]
```

Explanation -

- `arr[start:end+1]` would create a slice of `arr` inclusive of `start` and `end` index
- `arr[::-1]` returns a reversed slice of `arr`

```
>>> a = [5,3,2,1,3]
>>> a[0:2]
[5, 3]
>>> a[0:2][::-1]
[3, 5]
>>> a[0:-2]
[5, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the rest of your code, here's how you could implement the 'reverse' functionality:

```
A1 = [5,3,2,1,3]
A2 = [[0,1],[1,3]]

def swap(a1, a2):
    for i, j in a2:
        a1[i], a1[j] = a1[j], a1[i]
    return a1

print(swap(A1, A2))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 1, 2, 5, 3]
```